# Dropbox Headless Install - No Account Linking URL

Tags: dropbox, headless

When installing Dropbox on a headless Linux machine with their install script (https://www.dropbox.com/en_GB/install-linux) - after install, when the `dropboxd` script is run a URL to link the installation to an account should be displayed.

This is not being displayed, the `dropboxd` script just hangs and, using the python helper script, `dropbox status` shows either "Waiting to link to account" or "Starting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set Dropbox will it seems try and open a dialog in X. If `DISPLAY` is set but does not lead to an accessible X display (X forwarding but no X server on client, stale variable, access control, etc) then `dropboxd` will hang and rarely display any error output.

Solution: `unset DISPLAY` before running `dropboxd`

Note: I say "rarely display" - I did, once, get an X display error 11 hours after `dropboxd` had been hanging which led me to the `DISPLAY` variable I was unaware was even set.